# Prove $17 \mid 13n^{17}+38n, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If we put $a=13n^{17}+38n$, then we need to prove that $a\equiv 0 (\mathrm{mod} \ 17).$ We have
$$
a \equiv 13n^{17} + 4n (\mathrm{mod} \ 17)
$$
but I'm not sure how to proceed further. I can't factor anything but a single $n$. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n=1$ then clearly $17$ divides $13n^{17} + 38n = 51$.
If $n \geq 1$ is such that $13n^{17} + 38n = 17k$ for some $k \geq 1$, then
$$
13(n+1)^{17} + 38(n+1) = 13n^{17} + 38n + 13\sum_{i=1}^{16}\binom{17}{i}(n+1)^{i} + 38 + 13 = 17k + 17k'+ 51
$$
for some $k'\geq 1$.

Comment: I am listening to the down voter giving constructive suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Since $17$ is prime, then $n^{17} \equiv n \pmod{17}$ (Fermat's Little Theorem)

Hence $13n^{17} + 38n \equiv 13n + 38n \equiv 51n \equiv 0 \pmod{17}$